# Code order of execution seems wrong after resume, fine before, and it is linear code

Tags: android, gps

### UPDATE: I have added calculations back before setting pLatOld = pLat and some are using the old value and some the new value of pLatOld after a resume.  They should all use the old value, which they do the first time the activity is run.  It looks like the Math class code is using the incorrect values but only after the activity is resumed.  Straight inline code is using the correct values.  Is there a way to make the update of old to new happen after everything else in the code has executed?

I have searched Google and stackoverflow for execution order. Most of the replies deal with parallel threads but as this is linear code it is a much simpler issue and one that has me stumped.  I have stripped the code in the example below to simplify my debugging. Normally I make calculations between setting pLat and updating the pLatOld that depends on the difference between these readings.  It works fine the first time but after resume the previous value is also the new value so my calculations are showing 0 distance.

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null)
        {
            pLat = location.getLatitude();
            textData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textData);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.########");
            textData.setText(
                    "Lat " + df.format(pLat) 
                    +"\npLatOld " + df.format(pLatOld)
                    );
            pLatOld = pLat;
        }
    }
```

The first time I might get this as the output when I enter 38 followed by 38.1

```
Lat 38.1
pLatOld 38
```

This is correct.

But if I leave the page and return and do the same thing I will get

```
Lat 38.1
pLatOld 38.1
```

This is wrong.

In other words, the pLatOld = pLat seems to be executing before the code before it.

I have tried adding dummy calculations so the compiler knows I use pLatOld after it is set but no joy.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong here.

Comment: To make sure I wasn't just showing the result of a delay in the setText statement I added distance = pLatOld - pLat; and display the result of the distance calculation.  It is correct the first time but always shows zero after a resume.

Comment: What does *"if I leave the page and return"* mean? What is a *page*?

Comment: @Squonk  If I back arrow out of the activity then enter it again. By page I meant activity, screen, what you see when you look at the phone.

Comment: @AljoshaBre what is wrong is that the code works the first time the activity is run but does not work after the activity is resumed.  If you are saying you don't see what is wrong with the code, I agree.

Comment: post the code for `onCreate()` and `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

First time your `pLatOld = pLat;` is executed `pLatOld` gets its value from `pLat` which is `38.1`.

Output is therefore expected as it is, when it gets executed later.

Comment: If I enter 1,2,3,4, etc.  The first time the activity is run the pLat will show the last entered value and pLatOld will show the old one.  After resume, they both show the new value.  However, this latest compile is showing correct calculations on distance where the previous one did not.